# Should I use UIImageview or something else?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm starting an App that will display an image and users will click a "yes" or "no" button if they like it. Then once they decide, a new image will appear and the process will repeat. They will not need to go back to previously viewed images.

My question is would you use UIImageview to do this and would you use some kind of array etc.. or what? Also how would you hook in the yes, no, and next buttons to this type of layout. Would you use a pop up for the "next" button or have it appear somehow in the view etc.. the yes and no would be fixed in place.

The images they say yes to, will appear on another view in a sort of folder.

This is only my second app. The first one I started on wobbly ground, so I'm trying to get some sold feedback before I build the foundation. If you have sample code that would be cool but not necessary at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are showing only one image on the page then it is feasible to use one UIImageView and an array of images. When user wants to view next image same UIImageView control will be reused with different image.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it will be one image at a time. Will it work to have multiple buttons if I use UIImageview? One button in a sense accepts the image to their folder in another view and displays it there. Another button allows them to pass on accepting the image to their folder. And a third button will appear after they make their choice, allowing them to go to the next image.

Comment: Yes definately, you have to code in such a way that when like button is pressed its effect it reflected to the currently displayed image. I hope you are using database to store the likes.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I was hoping not to have to use a database. Any suggestions on a way to do it without that. Basically the image would just move to another view as I said, and they could keep it there or delete it. At least that's my hope. Couldn't I just do some kind of "if" statement if they click yes on an image that populates the imageview in the other view with a copy of that image. That is the point where it gets a little vague for me. But definitely wanting to find a way to do it without a database.

Comment: Database will help you in making the app more simple. Without database it will be difficult to store information regarding the images. If u don't want to use the database then there is only one option i.e. NSMutable array and NSMutableDictionary. You can make dictionary for images and same for likes

Answer (score 0):

The images can be shown in webview also but imageview is ok too. Better keep the yes and no button below the view for simplicity. To populate the imageview you use array of images and on clicking next button or whatever, you can load the next image in the array to image view.